# Reading a list of strings from command line in Java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, system.in

I am trying to read a list of strings from command line in Java and then print the strings. 
Here is the code: -

```
public class Example {
  public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = null;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      list.add(line);
    }
    System.out.println(list);
   }
}
```

But it enters into an infinite loop and never prints the list. 
Can anyone please help me point the mistake in my code?

Comment: Your `while` loops says that 'if you don't enter null then it will go on forever'. So you need to input null from console after you are done entering strings. You can do that by ctrl+D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the terminating condition inside the while loop will solve your issue.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        while(true) {
            line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null || line.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            list.add(line);
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a bug. What will `BufferedReader.readLine()` return when the code hits EOF?

Answer (score 0):

**There's nothing wrong with your code.** It doesn't terminate simply because it haven't got the correct "signal" yet.

Try `Ctrl+D` after you are done with the input. It should work for most cases.

Or `Ctrl+Z` for windows command line.

**If you are using Java 8. There's a shorter version**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ReadLinesFromStdin {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
                .lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(lines);
    }
}
```